# Selecting specific lines between characters of a text field formatted in HTML

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports, substring

I should preface this question by noting I have enough msyql experience to be potentially dangerous to a wet paper bag. I have a mysql table with a text field, Extra, that stores data in multiple rows as below.

```
    <values>
  <v n="Billable">50</v>
  <v n="CheckDate">04/29/2019</v>
  <v n="CheckNumber">12</v>
  <v n="Paid">35</v>
  <v n="PaymentMethod">Check</v>
</values>
```

I need to create a temporary table that will store the check number, check date and paid.  The CheckNumber value can vary, which is causing me some problems. I have used some variations of `mid(checknumber)`, but since the check number length can vary, my results are sub par.
my query:

```
SELECT substring_index(substring_index(Extra, '"checkdate">', -1),
                       '"CheckNumber">', 1)
FROM c01.tbl_invoice_transaction;
```

my results are:

```
<values>
  <v n="Billable">50</v>
  <v n="CheckDate">04/29/2019</v>
  <v n=
```

The data is stored with HTML coding, should I be using parts of the HTML code as the substring starting point and end point? All of this is required to make a temporary table where the user can search for a check number or check date with using Crystal Reports. Crystal does not let me make search parameters out of a memo field, which it how Crystal sees this text field.

Comment: This is not html, this is an xml fragment. Mysql does have some built-in functions to process xml data.